# ignore classname in `naming-convention`

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am using tailwind and react, and eslint.

I have the current configuration

```
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
          "error",
          {
            "selector": "default",
            "format": ["camelCase", "UPPER_CASE", "PascalCase"],
            "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
            "trailingUnderscore": "allow"
          },
          {
            "selector": "variable",
            "format": ["camelCase", "UPPER_CASE", "PascalCase"],
            "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
            "trailingUnderscore": "allow"
          },
          {
            "selector": "typeLike",
            "format": ["PascalCase"]
          }
        ],
```

But in the code, when I use classname library I have to do the following :

```
   className={
     classNames({
     'py-2 pl-8 pr-4 cursor-pointer ':true,
     })
    }
```

Which break the rules...

I would like to know if I can ignore the convention for anything in between `classname({***})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore everything inside a `classNames` call, you’d need something similar to the `indent` rule’s `ignoredNodes` that has access to the AST but I couldn’t find a similar option for `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention`.

A workaround would be to follow the documentation’s example on [ignoring properties that require quotes](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md#ignore-properties-that-require-quotes) with e.g.

```json
{
    "selector": "property",
    "format": ["strictCamelCase"],
    "filter": {
         "regex": "[- ]",
         "match": false
    }
}
```

If you're willing to change your code writing convention instead of your tooling configuration, you could also simply write the class expression differently:

```js
classNames(
  foo == bar && 'py-2 pl-8 pr-4 cursor-pointer',
  baz > 0 ? 'rounded' : 'rounded-xl'
)
```